# Flask выдает ошибку 400 Bad Request

Tags: python, mysql, база-данных, flask

Всем привет! Я заполняю таблицу tbl_employer, но у меня Flask выдает ошибку 400 Bad Request.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я вроде все написал правильно.     Вод код на Python:

```
import MySQLdb 
import pymysql
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from pymysql import cursors

AllLogin = []
app = Flask(__name__ , template_folder = 'templates')
db = pymysql.connect(host='127.0.0.1',user='root',password='12002-tnA',db='studentsworks',charset='utf8') #,user_unicode='True')
print("Connect OK")
cursor1 = db.cursor(cursors.DictCursor)
cur  = db.cursor()
Query = " Select id from tbl_employer "
cur.execute(Query)
AllLogin = cur.fetchall()
print('записи таблицы {} \n'. format(AllLogin))
for h in range(0, len(AllLogin)):
    print('Очередной логин {} \n'. format(AllLogin[h][0]))

@app.route('/input', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def get_data():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        ENTERPRISE = request.form['enterprise']
        LASTNAME = request.form['lastname']
        NAME = request.form['name']
        PATRONYMIC = request.form['patronymic']
        POST = request.form['post']
        PHONE = request.form['phone']
        EMAIL = request.form['email']
        PROBLEMS = request.form['problems']
        sql = """ INSERT INTO tbl_employer(enterprise, lastname, name, patronymic, post, phone, email, problems) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s) """
        cur.execute (sql, (ENTERPRISE, LASTNAME, NAME, PATRONYMIC, POST, PHONE, EMAIL, PROBLEMS))
        db.commit()
    return render_template('tbl_employers_3.html'
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug = True, host = '127.0.0.1' )
```

И на HTML:

```
<!DOCTIPE html>
<html lang = "en">
<head>
    <meta charset = "UTF-8">
    <title> Flask My Form </title>
    <body bgcolor="#FFFFE0">
    </head>
    <hr color="#8B0000" size="5">

    <table align="center" border="0" width="50" height="30">
    <h1 align="center"> <font color="#8B0000" face="Open Sans"> Sign Up</font></h1>
        <tr>
        <form align="center" method = "POST" action = "/input">
                <lable> Введи Название Предприятия </lable><input type= "text" name = "enterprise"><br><br>
                <lable> Введи Фамилию </lable><input type= "text" name = "lastname"><br><br>
                <lable> Введи Имя </lable><input type= "text" name = "name"><br><br>
                <lable> Введи Отчество </lable><input type= "text" name = "patronymic"><br><br>
                <lable> Введи Должность </lable><input type= "text" name = "post"><br><br>
                <lable> Введи Телефон </lable><input type= "text" name = "phone"><br><br>
                <lable> Введи эл.почту </lable><input type= "text" name = "email"><br><br>
                <lable> Введи Номер Проблемы </lable><input type= "text" name = "problems"><br><br>
            <input type = "submit" value = "Sign Up"></font></td>
        </form>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Заранее спасибо,

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: Проблема не воспроизводится. Код рабочий за исключением отсутствующей скобки в строке `return render_template('tbl_employers_3.html'`, но если бы была проблема в этом, была бы ошибка синтаксиса. Скорее всего у вас в какой-то момент было несоответствие имени поля problems в коде и в html.